# running a program in linux from perl

Tags: linux, perl

I want to run a program from perl by using system command(or any other ways ).

system("samtools");

I think it should pass this to shell but it complains ,Can't exec "samtools"  file or directory does not exist , when I run it.I have tried many other different program for example

system("velveth");

and it works properly but not this one (samtools). Is any of you facing this problem before?
I am really puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **give the full path** to that file location.

example:

```
system( "/usr/bin/perl -de 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Linux command inside `` characters. Will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify `$path` for `samtools` in the current shell manually?

Since `system` starts a new sub-shell to run your command, you have to append search path for `samtools` yourself if doesn't exist in your `.bashrc`. Check it by:

```
perl -e 'system("echo \$PATH")'
```

and

```
echo $PATH
```

to see if there's any difference.